# Meteor.publish -> All data still available

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, meteorite

In my server folder I have a file where i'm doing the following

```
Meteor.publish("all_jobs", function(jobs) {
    return Jobs.find();
});

Meteor.publish("user_jobs", function(user_id) {
    return Jobs.find({userid: user_id}, {sort: {date: -1}});
});
```

On the user his blogpost page I do the following:

```
Session.set("userid", Meteor.userId());

Meteor.subscribe("user_jobs", Session.get("userid"));

Template.userJobs.helpers({
   jobs: function(){
      return Jobs.find();
   }
});
```

On my homepage I would need all the blogpost. So i'm trying to access `Meteor.subscribe("all_jobs");`

The problem i'm having right now is that all the posts are showing up on my user profile instead of only the posts published by the user.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you make multiple subscriptions for the same collection, the [results will be merged](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/) on the client. After subscribing to `all_jobs`, the client will now have all of the jobs in its local database until the subscription is stopped. When you go to `find` some of the jobs in the `userJobs` template, you will need to indicate which ones you actually are interested in. Modify your helper as follows:

```js
Template.userJobs.helpers({
  jobs: function() {
    return Jobs.find(userid: Meteor.userId());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The problem was I was subscribed to all the publications because I just subscribed somewhere random in my code.

I fixed this by adding a `waitOn` in my route:

```
waitOn: function() {
    return [
        Meteor.subscribe("userJobs"),
    ];
},
```